# Why Unity Transform only allows to put up to 4 decimals?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to fix it or is it a Software limitation?

In C# I can put more than 4 decimals but in the Transform Component, only the first 4 decimals are appearing.

Comment: I see in the Transform component, more excatly in Position

Comment: I mean *where* are you seeing this value displayed? position is a `Vector3`, and if you look at it as a whole you will see truncated numbers. What if you do `myPosition.x`, for example? See [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/problem-transform-position-returns-vector3-with-1-decimal-place.159559/) for more info.

Comment: Also, what is the number? If it's greater than 100, then you will only see a max of 4 digits after the decimal, since there are three before the decimal (a `float` has a max of 7 siginifcant digits).

Comment: the number is -40.654897

Comment: 6 decimals if I count correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it a "software limitation". So, the Position in Transform of Inspector presents the number in float. If the decimal precision is out of the range of float (max of 7 significant digits) it will be rounded to float. Also, let's say, if you want to print position to console using Debug.Log it will be rounded further in accordance to .net rounding. However, if you are using the value in code behind, you can ignore what it is showing. For example, (double)transform.position.x = 97344.671875 will be shown as 97344.67 and there's nothing you can do about it (I have seen some people who create their own transform and show the values as you wish). To answer your question the only way to fix it is to create a customized transform in inspector.

Answer (score 3):

There is a software limitation.

Please refer to the [Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) there you can find

> **C# type/keyword      Approximate range                 Precision**
>   float                            ±1.5 * 10<sup>-45</sup> to ±3.4 * 10<sup>38</sup>        ~6-9 digits

Your value `-40.654897` has 8 digits.

---

However the `Transform` Inspector and Unity in general most of the times only displays a human readable representation of `float` values even though the actual value might have a higher precision! See e.g.

```
Debug.Log(new Vector3(0.0002356f, 23.123456f, -40.654897f));
```

output

> 0.0, 23.1, -40.7

this does not mean the actual value is changed. It just displays a better readable one.